# tinymce and ibrowser

Tags: tinymce

I have been trying to add an upload functionality to tinyMCE but have not had any luck getting it to work despite following several online guides.

Here are my steps:

1. unzip ibrowse into the plugins folder of tinymce
2. configured my folder paths in the config file of the ibrowse folder (ibrowser/config/config.inc.php) as such:

   ```
   $cfg['ilibs'] = array (
           array (                                                                     
               'value'     => '/uploads/pictures/',                                                
               'text'      => 'Site Pictures',
           ),
           array (
               'value'     => '/uploads/gallery/',                 
               'text'      => 'Gallery',
           ),  
       );
   ```
3. Gave write permission to these two new folders along with `ibrowser/temp` and `ibrowser/scripts/phpThumb/cache`
4. Navigated to `ibrowser/interface/tinyMCE/` and copied the two files (`editor_plugin.js` and `editor_plugin_src.js`) and placed them in ibrowse folder thusly replacing the current ones
5. Finally changed the init to as follows:

   ```
   tinyMCE.init({
                       mode : "exact",
                       elements : "message",
                       theme : "advanced",
                       plugins : ",layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,ibrowser",
                       theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "fontselect,fontsizeselect,ibrowser",
                       theme_advanced_buttons2_add : "separator,insertdate,inserttime,preview,separator,forecolor,backcolor,advsearchreplace",
                       theme_advanced_buttons2_add_before: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,separator,search,replace,separator",
                       theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before : "tablecontrols,separator",
                       theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                       theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                       theme_advanced_path_location : "bottom",
                       content_css : "example_full.css",
                       plugin_insertdate_dateFormat : "%Y-%m-%d",
                       plugin_insertdate_timeFormat : "%H:%M:%S",
                       extended_valid_elements : "hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
                       external_link_list_url : "example_link_list.js",
                       external_image_list_url : "example_image_list.js",
                       flash_external_list_url : "example_flash_list.js",
                       media_external_list_url : "example_media_list.js",
                       theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : false,
                       theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                       nonbreaking_force_tab : true,
                       apply_source_formatting : true,
                       browsers : "msie,gecko,safari,opera",
                       force_br_newlines : true,
                       relative_urls : false,
                       remove_script_host : false,
                       document_base_url : "<?php echo $SETTINGS["installURL"]; ?>"
                   });
   ```

But after this finally step the tinyMCE shows no new button

Any suggestions? My version of tinyMCE is 3.3.

UPDATE: I checked the console in chrome and it mentions "GET http://.../tiny_mce/plugins/ibrowser/editor_plugin.js 404 (Not Found)"

The file is on the server in the correct directory so what might be the problem?