# iBrowser not working with tinymce_3.5.8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, tinymce

I did following to add iBrowser Plugins to tinymce_3.5.8.

1) iBrowser folder copied to /tiny_mce/Plugins
2) Copied files 'editor_plugin.js' and 'editor_plugin_src.js' to iBrowser
3) Configured config.inc.php of iBrowser

```
$cfg['ilibs'] = array ( 
        array (                                                                     
            'value'     => '/tinyimages',                                               
            'text'      => 'Site Pictures',
        ),
        array (
            'value'     => '/tinyimages',               
            'text'      => 'Gallery',
        ),  
    );

$cfg['ilibs_dir']      = array('/tinyimages');



tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "ibrowser,autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "ibrowser,tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,


        content_css :    "style.css",

        template_external_list_url :"tiny_mce/lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url :"tiny_mce/lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url :"tiny_mce/lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url :"tiny_mce/lists/media_list.js",

});
```

I'm still getting icon to upload image. What could possibly went wrong ?

Comment: Permission has set properly. Not getting any error in console.

Comment: similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592938/tinymce-and-ibrowser?rq=1